# VBA loop enhancement

Tags: vba, loops, foreach

Got data from column A to K however I need to copy paste only from A to J to a specific sheet if the Column K = "TRUE" , is this possible with a For Each instead?

```
'if line contains XE copy to XE sheet
raw1 = Worksheets("RAW").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To raw1
    If Worksheets("RAW").Cells(i, 11).Value = "True" Then
    Worksheets("RAW").Rows(i).Copy
    Worksheets("XE").Activate
    raw2 = Worksheets("XE").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("XE").Cells(raw2 + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
```

Thank you for you help

Comment: Why do you want to do this with a `For Each` loop? Is it because you read somewhere that iterating object collections is faster with a `For Each` loop (it's true)? Note that using `Select` and `Activate` is likely defeating whatever gain you'd get. The main issue I'm seeing here is `Select` & `Activate`, not `For...Next`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing it slightly differently:

```
Sub foo()
Dim wsRAW As Worksheet: Set wsRAW = Worksheets("RAW")
Dim wsXE As Worksheet: Set wsXE = Worksheets("XE")

raw1 = wsRAW.Cells(wsRAW.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To raw1
    If wsRAW.Cells(i, 11).Value = "True" Then
        wsRAW.Range("A" & i & ":J" & i).Copy
        raw2 = wsXE.Cells(wsXE.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wsXE.Range("A" & raw2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried doing that however I am getting "Object doestnt support this property or method"  in this line  wsXE.Cells(raw2, 1).Paste, I tried to replace it with wsXE.Cells(raw2 + 1, 1).Select ActiveSheet.Paste but is not working either =(

Comment: @Juanjo please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thank you :)

Comment: Definitely, it was of great help

Comment: @JuanjoPiñaG Muchas gracias, yes it is marked now thanks! :)